# Sample application to communicate with and manage devices on the PCI / PCI-X / PCI-E HBA

Tags: c#, .net, pci, pci-e

I am a complete newbie to this.  I have been told to develop a 'proof-of-concept' kind of sample C# .NET application(s) that communicate with and manage devices on the PCI / PCI-X / PCI-E HBA. I do not have knowledge of the communication protocols involved here.  Googling isn't helping much or maybe my search is not optimised. All that I know well by virtue of my past experience is C# - ADO.NET.  Does any body have pointers as to how I should approach this and any reference links.  Any sample application IF already exists can be a huge help based on which I can replicate to our business needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking in the source code of the `pciutils` package (namely `lspci` which is used for querying PCI devices and `setpci` which is used to configure them) here: http://pciutils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1:3.1.4-2/files.html

However, without any knowledge of the PCI protocol it could be quite hard... I'd suggest first getting yourself familiar with the PCI protocol, and then its "extensions" such as PCIe (since it relies heavily on the "base" PCI). Try reading about it in Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI ) just to get an overview before delving into the details.